# MS Access DB query result to JTextField

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jtextfield

I'm trying to make - adding new record to the DB, information which will be added in DB will be inputed in JTextField, I'm trying to make that the first JTextField content will be next acceptable index, example,

```
Table_ID   Item1   Item2   etc
--------   -----   -----   ---
    1       www     rrr
    2       rrr     ccc
```

I know that I can get maximal ID with this query: **SELECT TOP 1 Table_ID FROM Table_name ORDER BY Table_ID DESC** and in result I will get **2**, but how to do that the JTextField content will be **3**?

Comment: While you can add to the max value, it is unsafe in a multi-user environment. You should use an autonumber, otherwise, you will have to write quite a bit of code to lock and unlock files.

Comment: I don't plan to use it multi-user system)